# RewriteRule not working for apache https request

Tags: apache-2.2

We have requirement to convert all http requests to https requests and append .xyz.com to the server name. For that i have written the following rule which is working for http requests but does not work for https requests.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}\.xyz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

If I type http:// lvldraspnetserv01, it redirects to https:// lvldraspnetserv01.xyz.com as required.

However, if I type https:// lvldraspnetserv01 it does not redirect to https:// lvldraspnetserv01.xyz.com, causing the certificate to fail.

Comment: You need a certificate for https://lvdraspnetserv01. In this case the certificate validation happens before the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} **Insert current condition here ***
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}\.xyz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} **Insert current condition here, but for https***
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}\.xyz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

Comment: I did not understand what do you mean by "**Insert current condition here ***" and "**Insert current condition here, but for https***"

Comment: Post your complete config above :-). I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Adding the `QSA` flag solved the problem

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}\.xyz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R, QSA]
```

Strange behavior isn't it ? :)^^